# How to run specific test suite in readyapi using ant tool from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, ready-api

We have a pipeline script in jenkins which is used to trigger build.xml of readyapi using ant as build tool. In this way its running all the test suites in sequence but now we want to run only particular test suite. Tried to used below code but its not working. can anyone please suggest some solutions?

Tried below

```
stage()
{
sh ''
 SoapUIPro ( pathToTestrunner: 'SmartBear/ReadyAPI-3.42.1.0/bin/testrunner.sh', pathToProjectFile: 'ReadyAPI-Projects/sample-soapui-test.xml', testSuite: '', testCase: '', testSuiteTags: '(tag1 || tag2) && !tag3', projectPassword: '', environment: '' )
}
```